# Resharper, skip tests by category ONLY in continuous testing session

Tags: automated-tests, resharper, test-explorer

1) Is it possible in Resharper, to skip tests by category ONLY in "continuous testing session", but for them not to be ignored if you just run them from R# test explorer.

2) Also does any one know if there is a setting which is stopping VS built in test explorer from updating, now R# is installed. It does update but is very intermittent